# How to get the latest row of the same foreign key in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have tried using max and groupby but it doesnt do anything

```
$posts = Post::join('immunizations', 'immunizations.foreign_id  ', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select(max(['immunizations.foreign_id  ']), 'immunizations.*')
        ->groupBy('foreign_id  ')
        ->get();


id  vacine_id     foreign_id  
1       1             6       
2       2             6      
3       1             8      
4       2             8
```

how do i get the latest row of the same foreign key

it should display something like this

```
 id  vacine_id     foreign_id  
  2       2             6       
  4       2             8
```

But what I'm getting is this 
     id  vacine_id     foreign_id
      1       1             6
      4       2             8

Answer (score 0):

Sort it first, then use `$posts = $posts->unique('foreign_id');`

Comment: `$posts` a collection or array ?

Comment: yes, i think you cant use unique() method in eloquent

Comment: try to use `distinct`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
->select(max(['immunizations.p_id']))
```

to

```
->select('max(immunizations.p_id)')
```

Altogether it should be looks like

```
$posts = Post::join('immunizations', 'immunizations.foreign_id  ', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select(['max(immunizations.p_id)'])
    ->groupBy('foreign_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: it says Unknown column 'max(immunizations.foreign_id)   SQL: select `max(immunizations`.`p_id)`

Comment: Please take a look now. Actually you were using `->select(max(['immunizations.foreign_id']))` previously.  So I commented on it. But in the meantime you have changed it to `->select(max(['immunizations.id']))`.

Comment: no error but im not getting the result i want it's displaying id 1 and 4 it should be 2 and 4